# rank values passed in subroutines

Tags: fortran, rank

I am having some issues with using multi-dimensional array in some fortran code I am writing.

Basically, I define a 2-dimensional array, which is passed to `membrane`, then have to pass a 1-dimensional version of it to `set`.

```
Case (1)
  Call membrane ("Set", scv(i,:), sty)
```

Here is the routine that takes the 1-d array.

```
Subroutine membrane (tsk, scv, sty)
Implicit None
Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: tsk
Logical, Intent (In), Optional :: scv(:,:)
Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: sty

Select Case (tsk)

Case ("Set")
  Call set (tsk, scv(1,:), sty) 

...
```

Here is my set subroutine

```
Subroutine set (tsk, scv, sty)

Implicit None
Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: tsk
Logical, Intent (In), Optional :: scv(:)
Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: sty
```

I then get this error when I try to compile my code

```
sct/btun/membrane.f:185:35:

     Call membrane ("Set", scv(i,:), sty)
                               1
Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'scv' at (1) 
(rank-2 and rank-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the routine `membrane` using a one-dimensional slice of `scv`. Since that subroutine is expecting a two-dimensional array:

```
Logical, Intent (In), Optional :: scv(:,:)
```

You get the error. I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but since you are accessing the first column of the array in membrane (hard-coded), I would change the dummy argument `scv` to be one-dimensional in `membrane`:

```
Subroutine membrane (tsk, scv, sty)
...
Logical, Intent (In), Optional :: scv(:)
...

Select Case (tsk)

Case ("Set")
  Call set (tsk, scv(:), sty) 
...
```

Note that that now the complete array is passed to `set`.

Alternatively, pass the complete 2D array to `membrane` along with the counter `i`, and pass the `i`-th row to `set`.

Comment: Right, I missed the fact that `scv` in `membrane` is 2-D and that `scv(1,:)` changed its rank. `scv` is a sequence of settings that will take effect when one is dealing with a membrane.

Answer (score 2):

"then have to pass a 1-dimensional version of it to set"

but the subroutine expects a 2D array because of

```
Logical, Intent (In), Optional :: scv(:,:)
```

Either fix the declaration or you must pass a 2D array.

Comment: And a 2D array slice can be passed as `scv(i:i,:)`.